# Div full size on image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to place a div full size of an image on top of it (like an overlay).
I can't set the width or height of the image because I want to keep the aspect ratio of the original image.
Example:

Original image:
[image]

With an overlay on top:
[image]

EDIT:

I was able to make the dark overlay on top using :before tags or simply adding a *filter:brightness()* property to the image. However, I'm not sure how to make a div so I can put text and buttons inside etc.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Setting only the width or height will  maintain the aspect ratio

Comment: Please make sure to read ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) at properly, least once, before posting a question. It's there to help you post a good question, and to help us avoid getting bad questions. Read it, and edit your post accordingly. And you're working on code: *show code*.

Comment: Seriously there are **hundreds** of "image overlay" questions on SO...did **none** of them help?

Comment: From what I found, using <a> tag is a good way of achieving this, I was looking to some other methods you could suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Create dynamic element 'img' and get image width and height:

if need vanilla **javascript**:

```js
   var newimg=document.createElement('img');
   newimg.setAttribute('src','https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFFir.jpg');
   newimg.onload = function(){
     var width = newimg.clientWidth;
     var height = newimg.clientHeight;
     newimg.remove();
     alert([width, height]);
      /* some more code */
   }

   document.body.appendChild(newimg);
```

if need **JQuery**:

```js
  var img=$('<img/>').attr('src','https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFFir.jpg');
  img.load(function(){
    var height=img.height();
    var width=img.width();
    $(this).remove();
     alert([width, height]);
     /* some more code */
  });
  $('body').append(img);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

if you set only one parameter ( only height or only width ) the image generally respect the ratio with the parameter, for example 
original image
width: 100px
height: 50px

if you set the width:50px the height will be automatically 25px